# My Array code shows no output, what is my mistake/lacking

Tags: java, arrays

As for a practice for java basic, our instructor told us to use Arrays that ask the users 10 integers then outputs the even numbers, odd numbers, and sum of all numbers. Somehow my code just shows 0, am i lacking some code or is there a mistake?

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.String;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ARRAY
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        String fire;
        int counter, value, clock, even, odd, number, total;
        int userArray[] = new int[20];
        int evenArray[] = new int[20];
        int oddArray[] = new int[20];

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10,10);

        even = 0;
        odd = 0;
        total = 0;

        for(counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter)
        {
            fire = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Array ["+ counter + "]:");
            value = Integer.parseInt(fire);
            userArray[counter] = value;
        }

        for(clock = 0; clock < 10; ++clock);
        {
            number = userArray[clock];
            total = total + number;

            if(number%2 == 0)
            {
                evenArray[even] = number;
                ++even;
            }

            if(number%2 != 0)
            {
                oddArray[odd] = number;
                ++odd;
            }
        }

        area.append("The even numbers are :");
        for(counter = 0; counter < even; ++counter)
        {
            area.append(" " +evenArray[counter]);
        }

        area.append("\nThe odd numbers are :");
        for(counter = 0; counter < odd; ++counter)
        {
            area.append(" " +oddArray[counter]);
        }

        area.append("\nThe sum of all numbers is: "+total);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,area);

        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Appreciate every help!
thanks.

Comment: It's way too early for you to use Swing. Just ask the numbers in the console, using a Scanner, store them in a **single** array of **10** elements (why 20?), then loop through this array 3 times to display the even, and odd numbers, and to compute and display the sum, using System.out.println().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logic, you have to remove the `;` after the for :

```
for (clock = 0; clock < 10; ++clock); 
//----------------------------------^
```

This mean end of of the for, the block between `{}` is useless.